# twitter4j getHomeTimeline Bad Authentication data

Tags: authentication, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

i am trying to get my getHomeTimeline using twitter4j. My twitter account is already authenticated a read/write access for the app and i have stored the access-token and access-token-secret. but when i try to access my account i get below error. any idea what might be the problem? thanks
Note that my twitter account is not the one that that created/own the twitter application

```
400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.
message - Bad Authentication data
code - 215
```

but all works well when I use the the access-token and access-token-secret of the account that created the twitter application.

i am using the jsOAuth.js library to authenticate the user and get access-token, and using twitter4j to query twitter

code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(prop.getTwitterConsumerKey());
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(prop.getTwitterConsumerSecret());
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);
configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();
try {
    twitter.getHomeTimeline();
 } catch (Exception e) {                
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

stack trace:

```
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=e5488403 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=09b41b0f
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[e5488403-09b41b0f], statusCode=400, message=Bad Authentication data, code=215, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:81)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1835)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getHomeTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:117)
    at com.alcrea.stc.st.server.service.mobile.MobileService.addTwitterUser(MobileService.java:346)
    at com.alcrea.stc.st.server.service.servlet.mobile.MobileServlet.doPost(MobileServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed, i removed jsOAuth.js library and used only twitter4j and it worked great. it looks like each library is uses different OAuth signature...

Answer (score 0):

Removed twitter4f 3.0.3 and loaded 3.0.5 and the issue was resolved.

sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "3.0.5",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.5"
```